# Multiple checks into one in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I know that this may sound stupid but I was wondering if this code could be written in a shorter version:

```
if (this.myVeryLongName.aRandomProperty === 'property_1' || this.myVeryLongName.aRandomProperty === 'property_1' ||  this.myVeryLongName.aRandomProperty === 'property_1') {
     //do something
}
```

maybe something like this:

```
if (this.myVeryLongName.aRandomProperty === ('property_1' || 'property_1' ||  'property_1')) {
    //do something
}
```

Is any way to make it short and still have same functionality?

Comment: `['item1','item2','item3'].indexOf(superLongThing) > -1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make an array and use `includes`, like:

```
if ( ['property_1','property_2','property_3'].includes( this.myVeryLongName.aRandomProperty ) ) {
    //do something
}
```

Doc: [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

Answer (score 1):

Potentially even better option (than the one I posted in a comment)

```
switch(this.myVeryLongName.aRandomProperty) {
case 'property_1':
case 'property_2':
case 'property_3':
  doSomethingHere();
  break;
// if you have more cases, add them here!
}
```

Notice how this is much more easily readable, and extendable in future if needs change.

Answer (score 0):

There's a variety of ways to do this:

- ```
  ['property_1','property_2','property_3'].includes( this.myVeryLongName.aRandomProperty )
  ```

  (ES 2016)
- ```
  ['property_1','property_2','property_3'].indexOf( this.myVeryLongName.aRandomProperty ) !== -1
  ```

  (ES 5)
- ```
  /^(?:property_1|property_2|property_3)$/.test( this.myVeryLongName.aRandomProperty )
  ```

  (Any JS version)